# Pod init error tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, command-line-tool

Im trying to run `pod init` command on my new project. 
It has never happened to me before. The things I have tried to fix it are:

- Closing Xcode
- Creating a new project
- Restarting my computer

The error I get in the console is:

````
error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance 

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod init
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.3.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
       Xcode :  ()
         Git : git version 2.15.1 (Apple Git-101)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ ed5bf5bee99a1909bcc8fb8ffa39fb08d1af6bc8
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Error

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:217:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needs to set your [CocoaPod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) and command line tool version, in your Xcode:

**Reset (Uninstall & install) cocoa pod:**

Execute the following on your terminal to get the latest stable version:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Use keyword `--pre` to get the latest pre-release:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

---

**How to set/reset Command Line Tool:**

You can download latest command line tool from [Apple Download Portal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12), if you have paid apple developer account/id.

Here are current beta and stable Xcode Tool and supporting command line tool download link. (Ensure you'are logged in using premium developer account on Apple Developer Account to access these links)

> **Xcode 10**
>
> - [Xcode 10](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10/Xcode_10.xip)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS 10.14)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_10.dmg)
>     
>    - [(Command Line Tool (Xcode 10) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.14_for_Xcode_10.dmg)

---

Once you've latest command line tool installed in your system, set it from Xcode Menu.

> **(Xcode Menu Items) Xcode ▶ Preferences ▶ Location ▶ Command Line Tool ▶ Select appropriate command line tool**

[image]

---

Try the same with Terminal App

Install Command Line Tools (using Terminal app):

```
xcode-select --install
```

Change the active directory:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Comment: thanks for your great and detailed answer but still no luck. I'll keep trying

Comment: @PabloMarrufo - try to reset your cocoapods (uninstall & install again), It should work....

Comment: that did it. You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I updated my xcode version to 9.1. 
I fixed the error with the below command. In your terminal just add

```
Sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

and enter your mac password. Then try with

```
pod init
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an another option to solved the issues. because of the issues happened in xcode 9.3, so i have create the project in xcode 9.2 , install the pod. and than after open the project in xcode 9.3 and start work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with cocoapods. I have resolved this with -

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
```

hope this may help to someone.